# Change execution timeout at runtime

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration, .net-3.5, runtime

In some cases, we build reports in ASP.NET that my require several minutes to build -- longer than the default execution timeout. Is it possible to change the timeout at runtime and/or for a specific page [and/or for a specific webservice method]?

We've experimented with [HttpRuntimeSection.ExecutionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to no avail (throws an exception at runtime saying `The configuration is read only.`).

Comment: I think you are better off exploring other options for generating the report rather than doing in inside of an ASP.NET web application, such as a Windows service.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Noted. And I agree. We'll be exploring something like that as time allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Server.ScriptTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524831%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) seems to be doing the trick for us:

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 600;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your timeouts in the webconfig file for the desired page

```
<location path="somefile.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
    <system.web/>
<location/>
```

Comment: I didn't realize timeouts could be set on a per-location basis in the config. +1